# () Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on null

Tags: php, getattribute

Getting this error irrespective of what i do and shows the same error again and again.() Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on null.
this my studentcontroller.php . 
   Getting this error irrespective of what i do and shows the same error again and again.() Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on null.
this my studentcontroller.php .

```
class StudentController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
     * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
     */
    public $layout='//layouts/column2';

    /**
     * @return array action filters
     */
    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
            'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
            'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
        );
    }

    /**
     * Specifies the access control rules.
     * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
     * @return array access control rules
     */
    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update','viewjobs','viewoffers','index','view'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Displays a particular model.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Student;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Student']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Student'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->st_id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Updates a particular model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Student']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Student'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->st_id));
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a particular model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->loadModel($id)->delete();
        $model=Login::model()->find("id=?",array($id));
        $model->delete();
        // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
        if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
            $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
    }

    /**
     * Lists all models.
     */

    // OLD ACTION INDEX
    /*public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Student');
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }*/

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Student',array(
            'criteria'=>array(
                'condition'=>'st_id='.Yii::app()->user->id,

            )));
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Manages all models.
     */
    public function actionAdmin()
    {
        $model=new Student('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['Student']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['Student'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    public function actionViewjobs(){
        //PPO accept Check
        $ppoCheck=  Yii::app()->db->createCommand("select * from offers where st_id = ".Yii::app()->user->id." and ppo = 'Y' and accepted = 'Y'")->queryAll();
        if(count($ppoCheck)!=0)
        {

            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('notice','You have already accepted your PPO and hence, will be able to apply to ONLY ONE company');
        }

        $stud = Student::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id);
        $st = new Student();
        $st->st_id = Yii::app()->user->id;

        $dept = $stud->getAttribute("dept");
        $programme = $stud->getAttribute("programme");

        $sql =  Yii::app()->db->createCommand("select count(*) as cnt from student where dept=\"".$dept."\" and programme = \"".$programme."\"")->queryRow();
        $totalReg = $sql['cnt'];

        $sql =  Yii::app()->db->createCommand("select count(*) as cnt from (select distinct(oTemp.st_id) from offers as oTemp) as o, student as s where o.st_id = s.st_id and s.dept=\"".$dept."\" and s.programme = \"".$programme."\"")->queryRow();
        $actualStudPlaced = $sql['cnt'];

        if($totalReg==0) $percent=0;
        else $percent = ($actualStudPlaced*100)/$totalReg;

        if($percent>=80)
        {
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('notice','Your dept is on a roll. More than 80% placed! You may now apply for a new job profile even if you accepted an offer before.');
        }



        $sqlcount =  Yii::app()->db->createCommand("select count(*) from job_profile_branches where dept = \"".$dept."\"")->queryScalar();
        $sql = "select * from job_profile as j, company as c where j.approved='Y' and (c.c_id,j.j_id) in (select c_id, j_id from job_profile_branches where dept = \"".$dept."\")";

        $dataProvider = new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array(
            'db' => Yii::app()->db,
            'keyField' => 'c_id',
            'totalItemCount' => $sqlcount
        ));

        $this->render('viewJobProfiles',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }

    public function actionViewoffers(){

        $id = Yii::app()->user->id;

        $sqlcount =  Yii::app()->db->createCommand("select count(*) from job_profile as j, offers as o where j.j_id=o.j_id and j.c_id=o.c_id and o.st_id=".$id)->queryScalar();
        $sql = "select * from job_profile as j, offers as o,company as c where j.j_id=o.j_id and j.c_id=o.c_id and c.c_id=j.c_id and o.st_id=".$id;
        $dataProvider = new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array(
            'db' => Yii::app()->db,
            'keyField' => 'j_id',
            'totalItemCount' => $sqlcount
        ));

        $this->render('viewOffers',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }
    /**
     * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
     * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be loaded
     * @return Student the loaded model
     * @throws CHttpException
     */
    public function loadModel($id)
    {
        $model=Student::model()->findByPk($id);
        if($model===null)
            throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
        return $model;
    }

    /**
     * Performs the AJAX validation.
     * @param Student $model the model to be validated
     */
    protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='student-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `$stud` is null when you are calling that method `getAttribute("dept")`. Please check.

Comment: so, why you do repeating the same phrase again and again?